# Sending Data to Server via Socket.io

Tags: ios, swift, socket.io

I need to send a topic list to my server. When I do it via Postman and send this :

```
{
"topics" : ["UUID78912","UUID87681"]
}
```

Everything works perfectly in the system and I am able to pass this data to my server. But when I do it in Swift like this :

```
self.socket!.on(clientEvent: .connect) 
{data, ack in

        print("Socket Connected")
        if self.socket!.status == .connected {
        self.socket?.emit("topics", CustomData(topics: topicList), completion: 
      {
        print(CustomData(topics: topicList))
        print("Completed")
        })
  }
```

Where CustomData is :

```
struct CustomData : SocketData {
   let topics: Array<String>

   func socketRepresentation() -> SocketData {
       return ["topics" : topics]
   }
}
```

How do I pass the data in the exact format like I am doing in Postman?

Comment: have you tried this: `self.socket?.emit("topics", CustomData(topics: topicList).socketRepresentation(), ...`

Comment: You Postman example looks much like JSON. Try to encode and send it.

Comment: It is text, at least that is what it is selected in Postman, if I select JSON in postman, it throws an error in my Nodejs server about 'Unexpected Token found' while parsing JSON (I use JSON.parse(data)).